# Verifying that $x^i e^{-a|x|^2}$ belongs to the Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), $x^i e^{-a|x|^2}$ where $i$ is a [multi-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation), belongs to the Schwartz space. This means that

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} x^{\alpha} D^{\beta} f(x) < \infty$$

where $f(x) = x^i e^{-a|x|^2}$

It's hard for me to see it because the derivative of that thing is something huge.

First let's break the multiindexes:

$f(x) = x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_n^{i_n} e^{-a|x|^2}$

then $$\partial^\beta f(x) = \frac{\partial^{\beta_1} }{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial^{\beta_2} }{\partial x_2}\cdots  \frac{\partial^{\beta_n} }{\partial x_n}x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_n^{i_n} e^{-a|x|^2}$$

Let's first try to see $$\frac{\partial^{\beta_j}}{\partial x_j}f(x) = \frac{\partial^{\beta_j}}{\partial x_j} x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_j^{i_j}\cdots x_n^{i_n} e^{-a|x|^2} = $$

Now things get huge, I need to use the product rule on lots of things. Can somebody give me a help?

Comment: You just need to prove each individual summand in $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is not difficult if you already have $\beta=0$, $\alpha$ arbitrary case.

Comment: @user10354138 what is an individual summand?

Comment: Note that since $|x|^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + ... + x_n^2$, you can rewrite $f(x) =f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)...f_n(x_n)$ where each $f_k(x_k) = x_k^pe^{-ax_k^2}$ for some $p$. So you can handle the dimensions separately.